# How can i use fittype function to define a custom equation?

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

How can I use fittype function to define the following custom equation?

```
y = a(x1^b)(x2^c)(x3^d)(x4^e)(x5^f)(x6^g).
```

I tried the following code:

```
ft = fittype( 'a*(x1^b)*(x2^c)*(x3^d)*(x4^e)*(x5^f)*(x6^g)',...
'independent',{'x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6'},...
'dependent',{'y'},...
'coefficients',{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'});
```

but it throws this error:

> Expression a*(x1^b)*(x2^c)*(x3^d)*(x4^e)*(x5^f)*(x6^g) is not a valid MATLAB expression, has non-scalar coefficients, or cannot be evaluated: Not enough inputs to FITTYPE function.

Comment: Your code shouldn't give an error. The error that you show tells us that your expression is invalid because `*` is not included several times, but it is included in your example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, 'a*(x1^b)*(x2^c)*(x3^d)*(x4^e)*(x5^f)*(x6^g)' is not a valid MATLAB expression. You should change it to 'a*(x1.^b).*(x2.^c).*(x3.^d).*(x4.^e).*(x5.^f).*(x6.^g)'.
Secondly, Matlab cannot process so many unknown parameters, a short one is OK, like this:

ft = fittype(@(a,b,c,x1,x2) a*(x1.^b).*(x2.^c),
    'independent',{'x1','x2'},'dependent',{'y'},'problem',{'b','c'});